# PowerShell Binary Module - Could not load Automation module in PS 5.1

Tags: powershell, module

I'm working on a PS Binary module and I developed it using `PS 7.1`. I tried importing the `dll` into `PS 5.1` and I got the following error:

> ipmo : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My `.csproj` file is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>assemblyName</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.0-preview-06">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="6.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This project is created by using the `PowerShell Module Template` via `dotnet cli`: `dotnet new psmodule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it backwards. If you want a module to be compatible with both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core, you need to develop it against PowerShell 5.1, then use the Portability Analyzer to determine how portable your module is.

`System.Management.Automation` houses most, if not all, of the PowerShell specific constructs. If you build against PowerShell Core, PowerShell 5.1 is NOT going to have the same version of that assembly loaded into memory. Hence, it cannot find the assembly version it is looking for.

[Here is some more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/writing-portable-modules?view=powershell-7.1#the-net-portability-analyzer-aka-apiport) you may find useful on the subject.

---

Edit:

If your module is not compatible both ways, you can develop it for PowerShell 5.1 anyways and use the `WindowsCompatibility` module from PowerShell Core which should implicitly make use of constructs only available in Windows PowerShell. There are some caveats, the module must not use "live" objects (like CIM, remote connections, etc.) and the module will effectively remain "Windows-only" since you can't run PowerShell 5.1 on Linux or MacOS.

Comment: I looked into this for a while, but I don't see what I could do to make it compatible with `5.1`. Either not use some features from a newer version of `System.Management.Automation`, or use a *hackier* solution as [here](https://github.com/PaulHigin/PSThreadJob/blob/master/PSThreadJob/PSThreadJob.csproj) (line 15).

Comment: I'm assuming because you're using `Start-ThreadJob`? Thread jobs are convenient but you should be able to most things, if not anything, work with `Start-Job` even if it requires a bit more elbow grease

Comment: But you are correct if you need a cross-runtime compatible module, you have to use the language features present in both. Alternatively, you can do language checks in the module before calling certain cmdlets. Believe me, I feel this pain. My code that runs on Linux is PowerShell Core but in Windows we don't yet have PS Core deployed organization wide. It sucks jumping between both versions.

Comment: In the end, I went with that *hack* from the `ThreadJob` GitHub page. I needed some feature from [Job2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job2?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) that is present in `System.Management.Automation` >= v3.

Comment: Can't say I've tried that with a PowerShell module but not surprised it works. That said I would think this could break the module within PowerShell Core if you use any functionality that doesn't exist in PS Core.